# dbms_utility.format_error_stack makes line break after line

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently working on a PL SQL script in Oracle SQL Developer where I added also some dbms_output commands for logging. The code bellow works perfectly fine, the only problem I have is that after the two lines (format_error_stack and format_error_backtrace) a line break is inserted, which I would like to prevent. The procedure down bellow is only a test procedure and should not generate any valuable output.

```
procedure test(
    i_key in number
)
is
    l_test  number := 0;
begin

    dbms_output.put_line('TEST - START PROCEDURE');
    l_test := i_key;
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST - Value: ' ||i_key|| '.');
    raise no_data_found;
    
    exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,1,4000));
        dbms_output.put_line('Backtrace: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace,1,4000));
        dbms_output.put_line('Test');
end;
```

The procedure above has the following output:

```
TEST - START PROCEDURE
TEST - Value: 1.
Exception: ORA-01403: no data found

Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "EXAMPLE.TEST_PROC", line 19

Test


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I already googled the problem as well as the DBMS_UTILITY functions but could not find any reasonable explanation on why there are line breaks after the two DBMS_UTILITY functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatted stack and backtrace both end with a newline character.

`LENGTH(SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,1,4000)))` returns 25.

`ASCII(SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,25,1)))` returns 10 - which is the character code for the newline character.

You then do `dbms_output.put_line(...)` which [adds a newline](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-19FA480D-591E-4584-9650-5D37C4AFA530) too:

> When you call PUT_LINE the item you specify is automatically followed by an end-of-line marker. If you make calls to PUT to build a line, then you must add your own end-of-line marker by calling NEW_LINE. GET_LINE and GET_LINES do not return lines that have not been terminated with a newline character.

You can avoid this by using `put` instead, and relying on the message always ending with a newline anyway. But as you are truncating the original value to 4000 characters it's possible that you could have a longer backtrace and you cut if off -  and then don't end with a newline, as it could be (or is likely to be) in the middle of a message, not the end. You could count back to the last newline but that is a bit messy.

Interestingly [the documentation for backtrace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_UTILITY.html#GUID-6AF22B6A-ED2E-4272-9159-9347C662060B) includes example code to print one line at a time, which splits the source text at newline characters and then uses `put_line` which adds one back on. That would allow particularly large strings to be handled, where trying to pass directly into `put_line` might error because it exceeds the [limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-CEC56D3F-3BA6-4CA0-8D53-E286AB6A0269) of what that can handle - i.e. if the backtrace is more than 32k.

So you might want to take that approach instead of only capturing the first 4000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is about line length (though, that's pretty *short* line, then).

See line #16, which extracts substring in length of 25 characters and causes "line break":

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure test(
  3      i_key in number
  4  )
  5  is
  6      l_test  number := 0;
  7  begin
  8
  9      dbms_output.put_line('TEST - START PROCEDURE');
 10      l_test := i_key;
 11      dbms_output.put_line('TEST - Value: ' ||i_key|| '.');
 12      raise no_data_found;
 13
 14      exception
 15      when no_data_found then
 16          dbms_output.put_line('Exception: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,1,25));                  --> here
 17          dbms_output.put_line('Backtrace: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace,1,4000));
 18          dbms_output.put_line('Test');
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec test (1);
TEST - START PROCEDURE
TEST - Value: 1.
Exception: ORA-01403: no data found
                                                             --> here
Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TEST", line 11

Test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But, if you shorten it to 24 characters, no more line break:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure test(
  3      i_key in number
  4  )
  5  is
  6      l_test  number := 0;
  7  begin
  8
  9      dbms_output.put_line('TEST - START PROCEDURE');
 10      l_test := i_key;
 11      dbms_output.put_line('TEST - Value: ' ||i_key|| '.');
 12      raise no_data_found;
 13
 14      exception
 15      when no_data_found then
 16          dbms_output.put_line('Exception: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,1,24));                 --> here
 17          dbms_output.put_line('Backtrace: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace,1,4000));
 18          dbms_output.put_line('Test');
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec test (1);
TEST - START PROCEDURE
TEST - Value: 1.
Exception: ORA-01403: no data found                         --> here
Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TEST", line 11

Test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Does e.g. `SET LINESIZE 500` (in SQL*Plus) help? Nope.

Why does that happen? No idea.